# How to define a model to use in grid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a razor view that will have two MVC grids displayed.  Each grid will have the results from a stored procedure that will return a list of data.  I am trying to determine what the model will look like.

What I have tried so far:

**Model:**

```
public class ResultsViewModel
{
    public List<YSM_sp_select_payment_history_Result> PaymentHistory { get; set; }
    public List<YSM_sp_select_comment_history_Result> CommentHistory { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    var model = new ResultsViewModel();

    model.PaymentHistory = db.YSM_sp_select_payment_history(vm.LoanNumber).ToList();
    model.CommentHistory = db.YSM_sp_select_comment_history(vm.LoanNumber).ToList();

    return View("Search", model);
```

**Razor View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<YSMadmin.Models.ResultsViewModel>
...
    @(Html
          .Grid(Model)
          .Build(columns =>
          {
              columns.Add(model => model.PaymentHistory.TransactionCode).Titled("Transaction Code");
              columns.Add(model => model.PaymentHistory.TransactionType).Titled("Transaction Type");
              columns.Add(model => model.PaymentHistory.TransactionDate).Titled("Transaction Date").Formatted("{0:d}");
              columns.Add(model => model.PaymentHistory.EffectiveDate).Titled("Effective Date").Formatted("{0:d}");
              columns.Add(model => model.PaymentHistory.TransactionAmount).Titled("Transaction Amount");
          })
          .Empty("No data found")
          .Pageable()
          )
```

I am getting an error when defining the columns in the grid.  I tried to pass just one of the results to the grid and it worked correctly.  But trying to define the model correctly is what I am stuck on.  Only showing one grid for reference.

Comment: Your controller code shows you are returning single object of type ResultsViewModel but the view uses IEnumerable collection. is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action code is returning single object of ResultsViewModel.

```
var model = new ResultsViewModel();
/* Other controller action code goes here */
return View("Search", model);
```

But you have razor view taking collection of ResultsViewModel. So, probably that is what might be causing issue with accessing model properties. So, please try updating your razor view as below:

```
@model YSMadmin.Models.ResultsViewModel
...
    @(Html
          .Grid(Model.PaymentHistory)
          .Build(columns =>
          {
              columns.Add(model => model.TransactionCode).Titled("Transaction Code");
              columns.Add(model => model.TransactionType).Titled("Transaction Type");
              columns.Add(model => model.TransactionDate).Titled("Transaction Date").Formatted("{0:d}");
              columns.Add(model => model.EffectiveDate).Titled("Effective Date").Formatted("{0:d}");
              columns.Add(model => model.TransactionAmount).Titled("Transaction Amount");
          })
          .Empty("No data found")
          .Pageable()
          )
```

Comment: why is it different and how does it help? please provide details to your answer

Comment: There are two results so I need to define which set to use in each grid.

Comment: @Craig Please refer this line: .Grid(Model.PaymentHistory). For the other grid, you can use Model.CommentHistory same way. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Craig could you post the error message. By the way did you get a chance to change the data type (from using collection of ResultsViewModel to single object of ResultsViewModel) of model that is used to construct this razor view?

Comment: @sam That works with the changes you suggested!  Thanks!